# LAN, Wireless, USB not working at all even in BIOS?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I have a laptop Toshiba Portage M800
The LAN card, Wireless card, USB not working at all

I made full format, I tried windows 7 32 and 64
I changed the wireless card with other one, nothing works at all.
Any suggestion here!?

[image]

Comment: This is the boot order of currently available boot devices. Are the missing devices actually enabled, elsewhere in the BIOS?

Comment: Yup I checked twice, if there is any other options! everything "enabled" in BIOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone have the same laptop with the same problem just check the BIOS

- Make it default, That's will solve the problem.